# Minecraft Freezing On Pop!_OS

Tags: java, freeze, pop-os, games, minecraft

I am Using **Pop!_os 20.04** on My second system (Specs at the bottom) which I mainly Use for STREAMING content and playing **Minecraft** when I go somewhere. I was Using Ubuntu 20.04 previously and I was able to play Minecraft, I also have **Windows dual-booted** I am playing Minecraft on it without any problems. But after I switched **ubuntu to Pop!_OS** I am not able to play Minecraft. The game launches and I can edit the options etc, but when I load a world or Join a server, The Computer just **freezes** and I have to **power off**. I managed to run the game by **capping fps at 20** and putting **2 chunks render distance**,
*but after playing for like a minute the game closes(not freezing) and the launcher shows a message showing 'Exit Code : 0'.*
This keeps on happening again and again.
The game freezes if I turn up my render distance, I can easily play with 20 Chunks render distance but I can't play put it on 12 chunks on Linux.

Someone, please help

**PC SPECS :-**

> CPU : Core i3

> RAM : 4 GB

> GPU : Intel UHD graphics 520

> STORAGE : 2TB HDD

**SOFTWARES :-**

> JAVA : 17.0.1 ([linuxuprising PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elinuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/java))

> OS : Pop!_OS 20.04

> Minecraft Launcher : [Official](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/store/minecraft-java-edition)

> Driver : i915

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: This is probably a driver issue.  `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` will tell you which driver is being used.  I would expect `i915`, or maybe `mesa`.  If you don't have i915 installed, then you'll need to figure out which package in Pop supplies it.

Comment: I do have i915 installed, check the original question please